# Excel, Barcode Scanner, Inventory

Tags: excel, barcode, inventory

I have no programming experience, yet I am in a desperate need for a help. I am managing a large restaurant/catering company where i once a month have to make an inventory of more than 1.000 products. I have an excell sheets, that are devided into a categories, for example for the kitchen, there is Fruits And Vegetables, Dairy, Frozen, Fresh Meat etc.

It is really hard, to go around using a laptop and do the inventory of more than a 1.000 items manually, so i was thinking, since I actually have a barcode scanner, if there is a possibility to just go around, and scan the products, after scanning a products barcode, excell would take me to the row of the products that corresponds to the scanned barcode.

Right now, if i scan the barcode with a scanner while in excell, it will just add the scanned value to what ever field i am in currently. so the scanner works, all i need is to capture that scan, compare it to the all barcodes that are associated with products, so it could take me to the QTY field of that particular product.

For example, if i scan a Star Anis product with barcode 23135165, the excell should find that product, which is as per picture in field B6, and than take me to the field F6, which is where the quantity should be entered.

\So, in short, i scan a product that is in a dry storage, the excell finds a product within 6 different sheets via corresponding barcode, and takes me to the field where i can enter the quantity of that product :)

This would save me hours and hours of work :)

can this be done? Thank you :)

[This is the picture of one of the sheets that i use when making and inventory.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZlS5.png)

Comment: I think you should benefit of having a column with all the barcodes for each product.
Then you could actually: 1. Scan the product to Cell A1. 2. When the cell A1 changes, a vba code could automatically do a vlookup and add one more to the quantity. 3. Then you could IRL go around and scan, and you don't need to enter anything, excel will just add all the quantities automatically.

Comment: You could just do CTRL+F to search and then scan the barcode to find it. But then the sheets must contain a column with the corresponding barcode of each product. To search in all sheets select the search option `Within: Workbook`.

Comment: Also, have you seen this similar question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54531202/excel-barcode-inventory